# Not included as an author in 2 publications

Tags: publications, phd, ethics, authorship, research-misconduct

Tldr: I was not included as one of the authors of 2 papers. What to do?

History: Around 2.5 years ago I started a PhD. I was producing very good results and my supervisor was very happy because there was a lot of data that could be published.

We did not have a good relationship, however. The relationship became very toxic, to the point that I had to look for psychological help. My therapist recommended I leave my PhD position. I put myself and my mental health first and took that recommendation.

Before leaving I talked with the Dean about my situation and the details of what happened. He recommended I put a formal complaint against my supervisor. After thinking about it, I didn’t file a complaint because I had a new job and didn’t want to think more about it.
When I left, my advisor and I did not end up on good terms because he “felt I was putting him in a difficult position and I was not appreciative of the opportunity he gave me”.

The other day I randomly found 2 papers that were published by my former supervisor, both on my research. My name was nowhere on the papers. Some experiments were copy-pasted, some were polished (but used a strategy I developed), and some were new.

**What should I do?**
Is there any chance to get my name added as a co-author? Should I escalate this?

Personally: I feel his decision not to add me was intentional as a punishment. The job I do now is not related to academia and I would not “need” the publications. However, I worked a lot and got those results during a time that was very difficult for my mental health. I subsequently feel my work should be acknowledged.

Answer (score 2):

I know one such case. It happened to one of my former students. After he left his first postdoctoral position, his former supervisor "punished" him like that. Fortunately for the guy, he had on his hands a considerable volume of proof of his participation in the disputed research: e-mails, computer programs. So he complained to the university authorities. After the university refused to act, he filed a lawsuit.

This endeavour lasted for several years. Eventually, the university hired a top lawyer who examined the case -- and recommended to the university to settle. As a part of the settlement, the university was obliged either to retract the publication or to ensure that the postdoc's name be added to it. The university also paid to him an undisclosed sum of money. The postdoc, on his part, agreed not to disclose the story.

Amazingly, the guy managed to defeat the university without hiring a lawyer. He himself was representing his interests in the court and in the subsequent negotiations. This does not mean that his victory came free of charge. He paid for it by his time, energies, health. Also, by the end of this saga he got so tired and strained that his relations with his wife deteriorated badly.

Now, questions.

(1) Do you have in your possession a formidable volume of proof to produce to the university authorities or in the court of law?

(2) Do you have enough time and health to allocate for this battle? Or enough dollars to hire a good lawyer? ('Good' means: having not only legal but also academic experience, and knowing the university realities.)

(3) If your answers to both questions above are affirmative, would the win be worth the trouble? Would it not be better to allocate your resources for activities more productive than litigation?

The old rule "pick your battles" is still in force.

Comment: +1 for pick your battles. Apart from or in addition to contacting the university, you can contact the editor. The paper would either have to be retracted or you are added as author. You may want to give [COPE](https://publicationethics.org/search?t=Retract) and [Retractwatch](https://retractionwatch.com) a reading